# ASP.NET: List of Page_Events via Intellisense? How do i know the signature?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, intellisense

is there a way to find and insert a page event via intellisense so i can get a list of what is available and the signature is automatically created?

Currently I create a page_init but with no parameters ... unsure if this is correct or no?

With controls you can take a look at Properties and then Events and you get a list of all events..

Any help really appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually override the methods in the base `Page` class which end up triggering the events, rather than subscribing to the events themselves. Intellisense helps there because as soon as you type `override` for a new method, VS presents a list of the methods which can be overridden.

The methods in question will be named On[Event], for example; `OnLoad()` `OnInit()` `OnPreInit()`. Just be sure if you use this method that you always maintain the call to the base method as well, which VS will automatically insert for you if you let Intellisense build the method for you.